# Selectively create folders based on names in bash script

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, ubuntu-20.04

I have several files called as follow:

```
dosulepin3D_CID_5284550.pdbqt
protriptyline3D_CID_4976.pdbqt
```

These are small molecules. Now I want to create a file in the `Results` folder for each one of these molecules, ignoring the `3D_CID_5284550.pdbqt` they all have behind, and have folders called:

```
dosulepin
protriptyline
```

I want to do this with a for loop, since I'm also performing some functions with these files. This is what I have:

```
DIR="/home/roy/MolecularDocking/VirtualScreening/Dockings"
cd $DIR
for ligand in ligands/*; do
    echo $ligand
    mkdir "/home/roy/MolecularDocking/Results/$ligand"
done;
```

But this obviuosly creates folders with the full name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this.

```
DIR="/home/roy/MolecularDocking/VirtualScreening/Dockings"
cd "$DIR" || exit

for ligand in ligands/*.pdbqt; do
    echo "$ligand"
    echo mkdir -p "/home/roy/MolecularDocking/Results/${ligand%3D*}"
done
```

Remove the `echo` from the `mkdir` if you're satisfied with the output.

See [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for more details.

Comment: Thankx @Jetchisel. This gives me `/home/roy/MolecularDocking/Results/ligands/viloxazine`. Is there a way of just getting `/home/roy/MolecularDocking/Results/viloxazine`

Comment: You'll need to do another Parameter Expansion. `ligands=${ligand%3D*}; ligand=${ligand/ligands}` maybe. The `;` can be a new line.